# How to Open PPT/Presentation file in webview in android?

Tags: android, ms-office, powerpoint

I have a URL of a presentation and i want to show this in the webview in android. I have tried the below code but it is redirecting in google drive app.

> String url1 =
>   "https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1nL5yO1HX_";

And my Webiew code is below:

```
WebView mywebview = findViewById(R.id.webview);

WebSettings settings = mywebview.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

mywebview.loadUrl(url1);
```

Comment: try setting webview client `mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient())`

Comment: @Manohar Reddy, thanks this worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used webclient and it worked for me

```
public class WebClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use setWebViewClient and getHitTestResult.It is use to get the url which will be going to open and then check whether it is ppt file or not.

First XML File :-

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"></WebView>
```

Main Activity :-

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String request)
        {
            try{
            if(webView.getHitTestResult().getExtra().endsWith(".pptx"))
            {
                try
                {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("url",webView.getHitTestResult().getExtra());
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                webView.loadUrl(request);
                return true;
            }}
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Then in new activity get value of intent :-

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String t=intent.getStringExtra("url");
    String s="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=";
    s=s.concat(t);
    webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl(s);
}
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    this.finish();
    super.onResume();
}
```

Second XML File :-

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: not working, webview showing file not found.